# Writing a long string to an HTML file, InputStream vs FileWriter vs BufferedReader

Tags: java, inputstream, nio, bufferedreader, filewriter

Im a bit confused on the best method to do this. I have seen alot of examples here on SO, and many answers have different solutions. So i would like to know the most efficient way to write a very long string to a new html file (i.e make an html file from a string). And is it really preffered to wrap everthing into a buffer? Like:

```
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(dir, appBook.getPath()));
    bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferWritter.append(htmlContent);
```

or  can can i instead do (without losing performace)

```
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(dir, appBook.getPath()));
    fileWriter .append(htmlContent);
```

..

This is the method i have been using for a while now:

```
//Will run out of memory if i dont split the string in 650000 chunks
    String[] bookPieces = splitString(htmlContent, Math.round(htmlContent.length()/650000));
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, appBook.getPath())); //.html path
        for (String text : bookPieces) {
            byte[] theBytes = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(theBytes);
            byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferData);

            while (bytesRead != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bufferData, 0, bytesRead); //add the bufferData data to the "new file"
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferData); // keep on reading and filling the dynamic byte araay until it returns -1
            }
            //need to GC the inputsteam myself!!!!
            inputStream = null;

        }
        toReturn = true;

    }
```

Than i read that it is preffered to use a BufferedReader for long text strings. So i changed to:

```
    String[] bookPieces = splitString(htmlContent, Math.round(htmlContent.length()/650000));
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    OutputStreamWriter oo;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, appBook.getPath()));
        for (String text : bookPieces) {

            byte[] theBytes = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(theBytes);

            InputStreamReader iReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(iReader);

            oo = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

            String nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                oo.write(nextLine);
            }
            //need to GC the inputsteam myself!!!!
            inputStream = null;

        }
```

But i cannot get the encoding right with that method, some chars will be different, like "—" becomes "ă€". And i still have to divide the string in chunks, so i dont see the purpose to change (am i implementing this the wrong way?, please tell me the correct way to do it with bufferedReader).

... And than i finally found two ways which are much faster and dont even req that i chunk the string to so many pieces.

```
    String[] bookPieces = splitString(htmlContent, Math.round(htmlContent.length()/100));
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = null;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(dir, appBook.getPath()));
        bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        //Has to append, if write than OOM.
        bufferWritter.append(htmlContent);

        toReturn = true;

    }
```

// And than one with Encoding which is slighltly slower than the above

```
    //Need to split large strings in 100 chuncks
    String[] bookPieces = splitString(htmlContent, Math.round(htmlContent.length()/100));
    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw= null;
    try {
        // Create osw and assign it an Encoding
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, appBook.getPath())),
                Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
        bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        for (String text : bookPieces) {
            bufferWritter.write(text); //write faster than append here
        }

        toReturn = true;

    }
```

Comment: `write()` isn't faster than `append().`  And you don't 'need to GC the input stream [your]self'. It's a local variable that falls out of scope when the method exits, and will be GC'd automatically. And nulling reference variables doesn't necessarily cause GC anyway.

Comment: Was just reading your answer on a similar tread, helped me with chunking the string :) .  If i dont make the inputStream null i will get OOM error :/, so it has to be lingering in the heap somewhere (running it on an android phone if that makes any difference).

Comment: Hmm, i stand corrected, just tried it and setting it to null doesnt make any difference. Before though, this little change stopped me from OOME for some reason, must have been something else than. However, Which on of these methods would be the best.  Should i wrapt it inside a buffer or not?

Comment: You should always buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple, yet more performant way to write the code, IMO:

```
int buffSize = Math.min(65536, htmlContent.length());
try (Writer osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, appBook.getPath())),
            Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw, buffSize)) {
    bw.write(htmlContent);
}
```

Notes on the code:

1. This version does not split the text.  The `BufferedWriter.write(String)` code extracts, converts and writes out the string characters in chunks depending on the `BufferedWriter`s buffer size.  Doing your own chunking is nugatory.
2. This version sets the `BufferedWriter`'s buffer size according to the size of the string being written.  But beyond a certain size (and 65K is a guess) you don't get any performance advantage by increasing the buffer size.
3. This version uses "try with resources" to prevent resource leakage.

---

Further ideas.

It may be possible to get more performance using NIO.

It may be possible to get even more performance by using *nasty* reflection to access the `String` object's `private` character array.  (Don't do this.  It is a BAD idea!)

A better approach might be to not assemble the HTML as a giant string.  Instead, write the characters / strings that make up the HTML directly to the `BufferedWriter`.  That avoids the need to hold the entire HTML in memory at one time<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Assuming you are using an `StringBuilder` without a good size hint, you will need up to 3N chars of `char[]` to assemble a String of size N.  If you have a good size hint, you only need 2N chars ...</sup>

Comment: I dont think i understand your points although they probably are good. I dont understand how the buffSize is used in your code? And i am extracting all text from a webview (this is the htmlContent) than i create a new webpage with that text. Try with req API 19 also :(

Comment: Corrected mistake.  See now?  For the stuff about not chunking, you need to look at the source code for `BufferedWriter.write` ... and see what it calls.

Comment: *"And i am extracting all text from a webview (this is the htmlContent) than i create a new webpage with that text. "* - That doesn't necessary mean you can't stream the data ... without buffering it all as a String.  It just depends how much effort you are prepared to expend.